# Android Application With ZooZ In-app payment system

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment-processing

i'm going to integrate ZooZ payment processor to my app. It's gonna be DEMO and FULL version of my app. What could be best way to determine if user has bought application, i think if would be insecure to check for boolean in SharedPreferences if's demo or not.

Answer (score 0):

ZooZ (a company which I'm CTO and co-founder of) have a server API to check payment status by email address. You can use that API and the user's email address to match a historical payment.

Also, it's always best to have a server of your own to manage that.